# Fluid simulation gives a obscured render when active fluid particles are absent

Tags: fluid-simulation

v3.1.2

I'm arranging a scene where a water fountain will pulse on and then be off for a while.

[image]

At some points, there may be no water particles inside the simulated Domain.  However, the rendering at these "no water" frames is of an somewhat opaque cube for the domain extents.

[image]

I've tried various materials, including some from an add-on "Waterial" and nothing is working.

Example [image].

Comment: Dumb question but can't you just hide the domain for the "no water" frames? I know the problem also occurs if you have for example a 300 frame animation but the fluid simulation only runs from frame 100 to 250. Then you have this domain "block" in the frames before and after the fluid sim.

Comment: @Blunder -- thanks for the suggestion.  If there were some driver function to figure out when there are no water particles withing the domain at a given frame, I'd consider that as a workaround.   But while I can perhaps use the Use Flow animation to trigger the enable-render, I'd need to know when to disable the render.   I want to be able to assign an animation function to the Use Flow property, so this would get tricky.  At the moment I'm using a cycles function, but might want a random noise function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is considered to be a [bug/open-issue](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/99591) by the dev team